# How to create a server socket in Ethereum?

Tags: node.js, sockets, ssl, ethereum, solidity

I need my Ethereum app to receive messages coming from outside through an SSL socket. I have no idea how realize it. Have you got any suggestion? I was thinking of creating a socket inside the app.js, but how? Can anyone help me, by giving me some code examples?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum smart contracts are not able to invoke off-chain services for security reasons.
So, creating a socket client inside your app is not possible.
In Ethereum world, Oracles are used to provide off-chain data to smart contracts.
Take a look at this [documentation](https://docs.ethhub.io/built-on-ethereum/oracles/what-are-oracles/) for some details.